# After denying location permission my application runs slowly

Tags: android

In my application,I have to ask user to allow ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission or not. If User Click on Allow on dialog box then further interaction with app is smooth but user deny it then application runs so slow.Any suggestion ?

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) {
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            Log.d("PERMISSION",permission);
            int grantResult = grantResults[i];

            if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("Action","Permission");
                    isLocationAccessible=true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("Action", "Reject");
                    isLocationAccessible=false;
                }
            }}}}    /*When log says Permission then further interection with app is smooth but when log says Reject then application runs so slow*/ @EdGeorge
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code,  the outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: The code that matters is, presumably, where you do different things based on the setting of `isLocationAccessible`.

Comment: I have not use that boolean variable yet.i just set it.If app run slowly then i will use it.

Comment: The code that matters is, presumably, where you _might_ do different things based on the setting of `isLocationAccessible`.  In other words, showing the code where you _remember_ whether the user granted permission is almost certainly irrelevant; what probably matters is the other parts of the code that are _affected_ by whether they granted permission -- i.e. where you are, I assume, asking for some kind of location information.